# How to delete a CAShapeLayer like eraser? (Not using another layer of white colour) - adding layers using bezier path

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

This is what I used:

```
UIBezierPath *_path;
shapeLayer.path = _path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.lineWidth =10;
shapeLayer.lineCap=kCALineCapRound;
UIColor *color=[dict objectForKey:@"Colors"];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

I am not able to delete the layer from in-between.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:REFERENCE_LAYER];
```

Keep a reference of the layer that you want to add. Then, you can easily remove the layer:

```
[REFERENCE_LAYER removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Comment: But i need eraser to delete a part of layer, not the complete layer.